# Reactivity order among Interhalogens

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, reactivity

I was reading about Interhalogens in JD Lee and in the book it is stated that (without any reasoning) the reactivity order for few of the interhalogens is :-
$\ce{ClF_3 > BrF_5 > IF_7 > ClF > BrF_3 > IF_5 > BrF > IF_3 > IF}$

1. $\ce{ClF_3 > BrF_3 > IF_3}$ 
   The above is the order for the interhalogens of type $\ce{AX_3}$ which I can understand by the fact that stability would be directly proportional to the polarisability of the compound. But the interhalogens are more reactive than halogens due to poorer overlaps in the first place and going by that logic the order should be reverse. But here that is not the case, Why is that?
2. $\ce{IF_7 > IF_5 > IF_3}$ 
   Going by the polarisability logic, this order does not makes any sense.
   According to me this may be explained by the steric factors, as the number of fluorine atoms around the central atom increases, repulsions between the substituent atoms increases so much that it’s stability gets affected. But the above statement is just a speculation. So what would be the correct reasoning here?
3. $\ce{ClF > BrF > IF}$ 
   The polarisability argument should be overcome by the poorer overlap at least here according to me but again that is not the case. Why?

[Here by poorer overlaps I mean, We know that for a strong bond, orbital overlaps should take place between the orbitals having little difference in their energies]

And my last question is it possible to theoretically determine the given below order with basic arguments(that is without any data), I suppose it comes out of net considerations of polarisability, overlap, steric factors.

$\ce{ClF_3 > BrF_5 > IF_7 > ClF > BrF_3 > IF_5 > BrF > IF_3 > IF}$

***Tl;dr*** (A) What is the reasoning for the given below reactivity orders?

1.$\ce{ClF_3 > BrF_3 > IF_3}$ 
2.$\ce{IF_7 > IF_5 > IF_3}$ 
 3. $\ce{ClF > BrF > IF}$ 
(B) Is there a way to determine given below order theoretically with basic arguements? 
 $\ce{ClF_3 > BrF_5 > IF_7 > ClF > BrF_3 > IF_5 > BrF > IF_3 > IF}$ 
[Note that in the book no specific mentioning has been done that is, it has not been mentioned reactivity with respect to what]

References:-
Concise Inorganic
Chemistry by JD Lee (Fifth edition)